# how to monitor the pressed keys from the keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms

While my application in background (not the active one)
I want to monitor the keyboard keys and in some cases, I want also to monitor the barcode scanner. The barcode scanner return a string of chars of unicode (which is not in the keyboard)

I found a class called  (GlobalKeyboardHook)
It work fine with keys come from keyboard

but with barcode scanner it dose not work

can you help me ?

Comment: Are you using PS/2 or serial interface to your scanner?

Comment: I have tried that kind of thing using onKeyPress, onkeydown in C# im using a barcode scanner we are using usb connector scanner, it is detected as another keyboard, so if youre going to use what i said it is already tried by me i hope we have the same case.

Comment: What kind of application are you writing? winforms, WPF, web?

Comment: @ivowiblo I am using winform

Comment: @DanzaiVer I am using USB barcode scanner 

but my barcode is 2D (the barcode image may contain a name not only numbers )

Comment: @NikolaMalešević I am using USB Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Distinguishing Barcode Scanners from the Keyboard in WinForms](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/)**

Some BarCode scanners just use keyboard inputs to enter data, but some don't. Read article to see how to detect BarCode reader input.

Comment: I read the article but I do know from where I can download the `rawinput.dll` reference

can you help me please?

Comment: Try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: I tried It,the first article refer to it also

I need the `rawinput.dll` to add to my project 

can you give me a link to download it?